# Aggregate query on multiple values of same field

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, pivot

I am using SQL-Server 2012, I have a table of credit card transactions as follows:

```
CardScheme  RespCode
=========================
Visa        Declined
MasterCard  Approved
MasterCard  Approved
MasterCard  Declined
Visa        Declined
MasterCard  Approved
MasterCard  Declined
Visa        Approved
Visa        Approved
MasterCard  Approved
```

I need to write a query to get the following results

```
CardScheme  Declined  Approved
==============================
Visa        2         2 
MasterCard  2         4
```

Please help

Answer (score 5):

Since you are using SQL Server you can use the [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function to convert rows into columns:

```
select cardScheme, Declined, Approved
from yt
pivot
(
  count(RespCode)
  for RespCode in (Declined, Approved)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3213c/1)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT
    CardScheme,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN RespCode = 'Declined' THEN 1 END) AS Declined,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN RespCode = 'Approved' THEN 1 END) AS Approved
FROM
    MyTable
GROUP BY
    CardScheme;
```